# What does "The proof proceeds by induction on $\sum m_i \ge 0$" mean?

Tags: algebraic-topology, induction, proof-explanation

From Rotman's Algebraic Topology:

> Let $X$ be a space.  A $1$-chain $\gamma = \sum m_i \sigma_i$ is a cycle if and only if $\gamma$ is homologous to a linear combination of polygons.
>
> Proving $\Rightarrow$:
>
> Let $\gamma = \sum m_i \sigma_i$ be a cycle.  If some $m_i \lt 0$, then a theorem says that $m_i \sigma_i$ is homologous to $(-m_i)\sigma_i^{-1}$.  We may assume that each $m_i \ge 0$. The proof proceeds by induction on $\sum m_i \ge 0$; the induction does begin when $\sum m_i = 0$, for now $\gamma = 0$.  For the inductive step, we may assume that each $m_i \gt 0$.  (The proof then constructs a polygon $\pi = \sum_{j=p}^n \sigma_{i_{j}}$ made from a selection of $\sigma_i$'s from $\gamma$.)  Thus $\gamma - \pi$ is a $1$-cycle to which the inductive hypothesis applies.  Therefore $\gamma - \pi$ and hence $\gamma$ is homologous to a linear combination of polygons.

How exactly is induction used here?  From my understanding of an inductive proof.  You start with a base case, make an inductive assumption on some $n$-th case, and then show that it implies the $n+1$-th case also follows.  But I don't understand how this proof follows this format.

Can someone explain what I'm missing here?

Comment: It seems like they're using _complete_ induction, where you assume in the induction step that your hypothesis holds for _all_ $m$ less than $n + 1$. Here the base case is $\sum m_i = 0$. They then assume the hypothesis to hold for all $\sum m_i \leq n$, and prove from that the case $\sum m_i = n + 1$.

Comment: This may be off-topic, what does $\sigma^{-1}$ mean? e: mathjax

Comment: @feynhat From context I'm assuming that $\sigma^{-1}$ means "traverse $\sigma$ backwards", i.e. for $\sigma\colon \Delta^1 \to X$ a singular $1$-simplex, $\sigma^{-1}(tv_0 + (1-t) v_1) = \sigma((1-t) v_0 + t v_1)$. Then $\sigma^{-1}$ is homologous to $-\sigma$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will just spell out Ben Steffan's comment more explicitly. I'm assuming that "polygon $\implies$ cycle" has been proven separately, because it should be less complicated.

Denote $\gamma = \sum_{i = 1}^k m_i \sigma_i$ where $\sigma_i$ are singular simplices. WLOG we assume all coefficients are positive, and proceed to prove "$\implies$" by induction on their sum $\sum m_i$.

**Base case:** $\sum m_i = 0$.

Since all coefficients are positive, the sum must be empty and $\gamma = 0$, so it is homologous to a sum of zero polygons.

**Inductive step:** For $n\geq 0$ suppose that the theorem is true for all $\gamma'$ such that $\sum m_i' \leq n$; then establish the theorem for cycles $\gamma$ such that $\sum m_i = n+1$.

Then you say the proof constructs a polygon $\pi = \sum_{j=1}^l m_{i_j}\sigma_{i_j}$ (and hence a cycle) for some non-empty subset of indices $I = \{i_1,\dots, i_l\} \subset \{1,\dots, k\}$. If $k = l$ then $\gamma = \pi$ is already a polygon so we are done, so suppose $k < l$. Since $\gamma$ was assumed to be a cycle the difference $\gamma - \pi$ is then also a cycle, but $\gamma - \pi = \sum_{i\notin I} m_i \sigma_i$ and since $l \neq k$ the sum of these coefficients must be $\leq n$, so by "complete induction" (also known as "strong induction") $\gamma - \pi$ is homologous to a linear combination of polygons, and therefore so is $\gamma = (\gamma - \pi) + \pi$.